# Intellij Idea doesn't compile my project after switch from JDK 1.6 to 1.7

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I created an Intellij project under JDK 1.6. Then I installed JDK 1.7 and removed JDK 1.6.

When I opened the project, I changed JDK to 1.7 in the *Project structure* dialog.

[image: Project structure dialog box]

But my files are not recompiled - if I add errors into my code and select *Build -> Rebuild project*, no compiler errors appear.

I also tried *File -> Invalidate caches* without any result.

How can I enable compilation of my source code again?

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4 Ultimate.

*Update 1 (23.09.2013 18:48 MSK):* I forgot to mention that all Java files appear with a small red J near them.

[image: Small red J]

Comment: Is your source directory marked as being a `Source Root`?

Comment: @maba See my answer below. I opened the wrong project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this strange behaviour was that there was a nested Intellij project inside the one I opened. When I opened the child project, the compilation started to work.

Answer (score 2):

I had to go to Project Settings > Modules and set the Source directory so intellij would know where to look. Thank you, @maba, for that comment

Answer (score 0):

Wipe out the files in your compiler output directory (usually *projectdir/out*). IntelliJ only compiles changed files and the files themselves haven't changed, so you'll need to wipe out the .class files compiled under the previous JDK.

Comment: Deleting everything from the *out* directory didn't help.